# php date time month -1 why doesnt return 02?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$lastMonth = (new DateTime())->modify('-1 month')->format('Y-m');
echo $lastMonth;
```

Why this returns 2019-03?

Comment: because there is no `29`th in last month (`feb 2019`), currently `format('Y-m-d')` will be `2019-03-01` and tomorrow it will be `2019-03-02` and day after tomorrow it will be `2019-03-03`

Answer (score 2):

> -1 month could produce incorrect results as some months have 31 days.

Use `last day of previous month`

```
$d = new DateTime( date("Y-m-d") );
$d->modify('last day of previous month' );
echo $d->format( 'Y-m' );
```

Comment: This is a clever solution...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, thanks for valuable appreciation! Glad to get it from a knowledgeable person.